# SQL Server 2008 select data only between month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, between, datepart

I would like select data between two date, without day

An input example:

start month: 9 , start year: 2011
end month: 3, end year: 2012

I think that there are two way to do this.

The first is convert start month and start year to date like `2011-09-01` and convert last date to `2012-03-31`, but this requires calculation of the last day of end month. Obtained these date we can use a BEETWEN function for the WHERE clause (but, is the CONVERT function reliable?)

The second solution is to use the `DATEPART` function like in the following code:

I try to explain: if end year is equal to the initial year, then month must be between the start and end months; else if the final months is greater than the initial years if different from the initial and final year, I take everything in between; else if the final year, the month must be less than or equal to the final month, if the initial year, month must be greater than or equal to the final month

Can you help me do this in the best way? Is correct, the solution I adopted?

```
declare @IndDebitoCredito bit,@ProgTributo int,@mi as integer,@ai as integer,@mf as integer,@af as integer,@IDAnagrafica varchar(5)
select @mi = 01,@ai = 2011,@mf = 12,@af = 2011,@IDAnagrafica = 'DELEL',@IndDebitoCredito = 1
select distinct rrd.IDTributo
    from TBWH_Delega d
    --inner join TBWH_SezioneDelega sd on d.IDDelega = sd.IDDelega
    inner join TBWH_Rigo rd on rd.IDDelega = d.IDDelega
    inner join TBWH_RataRigo rrd on rrd.IDRigo = rd.IDRigo 
    where
    (
        DATEPART(MM,d.DataDelega)<=@mf and 
        DATEPART(MM,d.DataDelega)>=@mi and 
        DATEPART(YYYY,d.DataDelega)=@ai and 
        @af = @ai
    ) 
    OR
    (
        --anno finale magg. anno iniziale
        @af > @ai AND
        ( 
            (   -- delega nell'intervallo
                DATEPART(YYYY,d.DataDelega)<@af AND 
                DATEPART(YYYY,d.DataDelega)>@ai
                -- DATEPART(MM,d.DataDelega)>=@mi 
            )
            OR
            (   -- delega limite destro
                DATEPART(YYYY,d.DataDelega)=@af AND 
                DATEPART(MM,d.DataDelega)<=@mf 
            )
            OR
            (   -- delega limite sinistro
                DATEPART(YYYY,d.DataDelega)=@ai AND 
                DATEPART(MM,d.DataDelega)>=@mi 
            )
        )
    )
```

GO

Comment: At first, I thought the final GO was for us: "Here's is the question. Now.. GO!" :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution is almost there, but is more complicated than it needs to be and won't work anyway. It will miss out any rows from the last day of the end month.

You can add one month to the `end month` and then use BETWEEN on the first of each month. eg.

`start month: 9 , start year: 2011 
end month: 3, end year: 2012`

`BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2012-04-01'`

or, as JNK points out, this will be better:

`DataDelega >= '2011-09-01' AND DataDelega < '2012-04-01'`

You'll need to add in some logic to deal with the `end month` being December, but this looks like the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: Except `BETWEEN` is inclusive so  this will include `4/1/2012`.

Comment: You're right - it will include any rows from `'2012-04-01 00:00:000'`. Without seeing the data in question, I don't know if this is a problem or not.

Comment: He says in the question he wants to only include data up to the end of the final month.

Answer (score 1):

You are **WAY** overcomplicating this.  You really only need two comparisons:

- Is the month and year after or equal to the initial value?
- Is the month and year before or equal to the final value?

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Datefield BETWEEN 
     CAST(@mi as varchar) + '/1/' + CAST(@ai as varchar) 
     -- first of first month
     AND
     DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(Month, + 1, (CAST(@mf as varchar) + '/1/' + CAST(@af as varchar))))) 
     -- Last day or final month
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the ISO-8601 standard date format: `YYYYMMDD` since that's indepedent of any language/regional settings in SQL Server - on my server, a  `10/1/2011` would be interpreted as 10th of January 2011, for instance.....

Comment: @marc_s - good point, this will be region specific as written

Comment: Due to regional settings, I can't test this, but will it include rows from the last day of the last month? Yes, if the `DateField` is a Date and not a Datetime. Or if the time portion is always set to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM Table
 WHERE DateField
       BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4), @ai) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @mi), 2) + '01', 112)
           AND DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4), @af) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @mf), 2) + '01', 112)))
```

Avoid using expressions on the DateField columns, as it makes query not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
WHERE DateToCheck >=               --- first day of StartMonth
          DATEADD( mm, @StartMonth-1,
                   DATEADD( yy, @StartYear-2000, '2000-01-01') 
                 )
  AND DateToCheck <                --- first day of next month (after EndMonth)
          DATEADD( mm, @EndMonth,
                   DATEADD( yy, @EndYear-2000, '2000-01-01') 
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mi INT
  , @ai INT
  , @mf INT
  , @af INT
SELECT  @mi = 01
      , @ai = 2011
      , @mf = 12
      , @af = 2011

--local variables to hold dates
DECLARE @i DATETIME
  , @f DATETIME

--build strings to represent dates in YYYYMMDD format
--add a month to the @f date
SELECT  @i = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @ai) + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @mi),
                                              2) + '01'
      , @f = DATEADD(month, 1,
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @af) + RIGHT('0'
                                                      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @mf),
                                                      2) + '01')

--select data where date >= @i, and < @f
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   DateField >= @i
        AND DateField < @f
```