# Take records between Month and year combination in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

anyone have any idea how to select data between month and year combination. Here is my code.

```
DECLARE @StartYear int
DECLARE @EndYear int
DECLARE @StartMonth int
DECLARE @EndMonth int

SET @StartYear = DATEPART(Year,'01-01-1753')
SET @StartMonth = DATEPART(Month,'01-01-1753')
SET @EndYear  = DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()))
SET @EndMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()))


SELECT station_id,
      DATEPART(YEAR,date_time) AS YEAR,
      DATEPART(MONTH,date_time) AS MONTH,
      CONVERT(date,date_time) AS DATE,
      DATENAME(weekday,date_time) AS weekday,
        sum(volume) AS Total_volume
   FROM rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly 
   WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,date_time) > @StartMonth AND DATEPART(YEAR,date_time)= @StartYear
   AND DATEPART(MONTH,date_time) <= @EndMonth AND DATEPART(YEAR,date_time)= @EndYear
   GROUP BY station_id,
        CONVERT(date,date_time),
        DATEPART(MONTH,date_time),
        DATEPART(YEAR,date_time),
        DATENAME(weekday,date_time)
```

I have tried something like this, But it returns no date even when there is data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917452/1477051

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 select data only between month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917235/sql-server-2008-select-data-only-between-month-and-year)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by GROUPing BY with so many fields? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

use functions to calculate the first days of the year-months (for the end date, add one month), then use them with `>=` and `<` against the `date_time` column:

```
WHERE date_time >= DATEADD(year, 
                           @StartYear-2000, 
                           DATEADD(month, @StartMonth-1, '20000101'))
  AND date_time <  DATEADD(year, 
                           @EndYear-2000, 
                           DATEADD(month, 1+@EndMonth-1, '20000101'))
```

Answer (score 0):

i looked at 2 links here below and i personnaly prefer numbers :

```
where datepart(year, date_time) * 100 + datepart(month, date_time) 
between @startyear *100 + @startmonth 
and @endyear *100 + @endmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a start date and a end date and you want to select all the records that falls between these dates including the records which have same month and year as these dates, then I think you need not have to extract the month and year part explicitly, rather try the following:

Get first day of next month of @EndDate by replacing `GETDATE()` with @EndDate in the following expression:

```
DATEADD(mm,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, GETDATE()),101))
```

Get first day of the month of @StartDate by replacing `GETDATE()` with @StartDate in the following expression:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, GETDATE()),101)
```

Use these two expressions in `WHERE` condition as below

```
...
WHERE your_date_field >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-DAY(@StartDate)+1, @StartDate),101)
  AND your_date_field < DATEADD(mm,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1, GETDATE()),101))
```